# count() corresponding to max() of different values satisfying some condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have the following tables:

**user_group**

```
usergrp_id      bigint     Primary Key
usergrp_name    text
```

**user**

```
user_id             bigint     Primary Key
user_name           text
user_usergrp_id     bigint
user_loc_id         bigint
```

`user_usergrp_id` has its corresponding id from the user_group table
`user_loc_id` has its corresponding id(branch_id) from the branch table.

**branch**

```
branch_id      bigint     Primary Key
branch_name    text
branch_type    smallint
```

`branch_type` By default is set as 1. Although it may contain any value in between 1 and 4.

**user_projects**

```
proj_id          bigint     Primary Key
proj_name        text
proj_branch_id   smallint
```

`proj_branch_id` has its corresponding id(branch_id) from the branch table.

**user_approval**

```
appr_id           bigint     Primary Key
appr_prjt_id      bigint
appr_status       smallint
appr_approval_by  bigint
```

`appr_approval_by` has its corresponding id(user_id) from the user table
`appr_status` may contain different status values like 10,20,30... for a single `appr_prjt_id`

**user_group**

```
usergrp_id | usergrp_name
-------------------------
    1      | Admin
    2      | Manager
```

**user**

```
user_id | user_name | user_usergrp_id |user_loc_id
---------------------------------------------------
    1   | John      |      1          |     1
    2   | Harry     |      2          |     1
```

**branch**

```
branch_id | branch_name | branch_type
-------------------------------------
    1     |  location1  |    2
    2     |  location2  |    1
    3     |  location3  |    4
    4     |  location4  |    2
    5     |  location4  |    2
```

**user_projects**

```
proj_id | proj_name | proj_branch_id
------------------------------------
    1   | test1      |       1
    2   | test2      |       2
    3   | test3      |       1
    4   | test4      |       3
    5   | test5      |       1
    6   | test5      |       4
```

**user_approval**

```
appr_id | appr_prjt_id | appr_status | appr_approval_by
-------------------------------------------------------
    1   |    1         |     10      |     1
    2   |    1         |     20      |     1
    3   |    1         |     30      |     1
    4   |    2         |     10      |     2
    5   |    3         |     10      |     1
    6   |    3         |     20      |     2
    7   |    4         |     10      |     1
    8   |    4         |     20      |     1
```

**Condition:** The output must take the `MAX()` value of `appr_status` for each `appr_prjt_id` and count it.

I.e., in  the above table `appr_prjt_id=1` has 3 different status: 10, 20, 30. Its count must only be shown for status corresponding to 30 in the output (not in the statuses 10 and 20), corresponding to a user group in a particular `branch_name`. Similarly for each of the other id's in the field `appr_prjt_id`

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/f5243)

**Desired Output:**

```
                           10   |    20  |  30

         ------> Admin     0    |    1   |   1
         |
location1
         |
         ------> Manager   1    |    1   |   0
```

How can I do that?

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/f5243)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/f5243/3)

```
select
    branch_name, usergrp_name,
    sum((appr_status = 10)::integer) "10",
    sum((appr_status = 20)::integer) "20",
    sum((appr_status = 30)::integer) "30"
from
    (
        select distinct on (appr_prjt_id)
            appr_prjt_id, appr_approval_by, appr_status
        from user_approval
        order by 1, 3 desc
    ) ua
    inner join
    users u on ua.appr_approval_by = u.user_id
    inner join
    user_group ug on u.user_usergrp_id = ug.usergrp_id
    inner join
    branch b on u.user_loc_id = b.branch_id
group by branch_name, usergrp_name
order by usergrp_name
```

The classic solution, that works in most DBMSs is to use a `case`:

```
select
    branch_name, usergrp_name,
    sum(case appr_status when 10 then 1 else 0 end) "10",
```

But Postgresql has the boolean type and it has a cast to integer (`boolean::integer`) resulting in 0 or 1 which makes for less verbose code.

In this case it is also possible to do a `count` in instead of a `sum`:

```
select
    branch_name, usergrp_name,
    count(appr_status = 10 or null) "10",
```

I indeed prefer the `count` but I have the impression that it is harder to understand. The trick is to know that `count` counts anything not null and that a (`true` or null) is `true` and a (`false` or null) is null so it will count whenever the condition is true.

Comment: What is this part for: `order by 1, 3 desc` ?

Comment: @saji It means order by the 1st column of the select then by the 3th

Comment: +1 for `COUNT` trick, even if I have no idea if it is faster in any way.

Comment: Brilliant answer.Thank you very much.Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto : Just to clear my doubt, as you can see in the table user_approval,appr_prjt_id=1 has 3 different statuses namely 10,20 ,30. And the next status will be 40 and so on. So is it possible to show that there is a project whose status is waiting to be 40?

Comment: @harry You mean in the same query? To show the next status of every project? I'm confused. Would you care to open another question?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Its exactly to show the count corresponding to next status of every project.In this case count should be 1 corresponding to status 40. Following your suggestion I've created a question.Please take a look at it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741191/show-the-count-based-on-some-condition